# how to execute a function each time you run python shell

Tags: python

I want to know how (if there is a way) to write a function and have it automatically defined when you start a python shell, or to keep certain defined functions after the shell closes so you don't have to keep re defining it if you use it a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can, you need to set your environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` to a python script you would like to be executed at every python startup.

By convention, such files are named by adding the **rc** suffix to the program name you're trying to tweak, and are usually located at the root of your home directory. In that case I would create the python file under `$HOME/.pythonrc` and then run `export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc` (for UNIX-like systems, it could be slightly different on Windows if you don't have a MinGW or equivalent).

Here's an example of `.pythonrc` file that you can play with: https://gist.github.com/twneale/5245670